# ValueError in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('hand.jpg',0)

height = np.size(img,0)
width = np.size(img,1)

cx = 112
cy = 131

j = 0       #initilalise
tmp=[]      #initilalise

for i in range(1,height):
    if img[i,cy]>0:
        j = j+1
        tmp.insert(j,i)
    xr = max(tmp)
    yr = cy
print tmp   
print (cr,cy)
```

While executing the above code I had encountered a ValueError

```
xr = max(tmp)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Please help me to solve the above problem

Comment: As it is clearly stated in the error message, your `tmp` variable is empty. Thus you cant call `max()` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

img = cv2.imread('hand.jpg',0)

height = np.size(img,0)
width = np.size(img,1)

cx = 113
cy = 130

j1 = 0      #initilalise
tmp=[]      #initilalise

for i in range(1,height):
    if img[i,cy]>0:
        j1 = j1+1
        tmp.append(i)
    if len(tmp) !=0:
        xr = max(tmp)
        yr = cy 
print (xr,yr)
```

This above block of code solves the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `max(tmp)` are executed before `if` branch executed. So, you should check if tmp is empty

```
if len(tmp) != 0:
    xr = max(tmp)
```